# Notepad++, replace with regular expression and maintain some variable letters

Tags: notepad++, regex

Example, I have a file that contains many many of the next:

```
"xxxxxx".toLowerCase()
```

`xxxxxx` - some text with variable length.

I want to replace it with:

```
castlowercase("xxxxxx")
```

I don't find how to make a regular expression. It's better to take everything between ( ) cause there may be some variable, not just a string...

Comment: Notepad don't have regex functionality. Do you mean notepad++?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I use notepad++ for so long time that I forgot that notepad exists too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `("[^"]+")\.toLowerCase\(\)`
- Replace with: `castlowercase\($1\)`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(                   # start group 1
    "               # a quote
    [^"]+           # 1 or more any character that is not a quote
    "               # a quote
)                   # end group 1
\.                  # a dot
toLowerCase\(\)     # literally toLowerCase()
```

**Replacement:**

```
castlowercase       # literally
\(                  # openning parenthesis, must be escaped in Notepad++
$1                  # content of group 1 (i.e. "xxxxxxx")
\)                  # closing parenthesis, must be escaped in Notepad++
```

**Result for given example:**

```
castlowercase("xxxxxx")
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Notepad can't do regular expressions. It is a very basic editor.
So you are asking the impossible.

Comment: Really? I see that there is an option 'regular expression' :/ oh, ok, I see that there are online regex editors, but I need to understand how to make this replace with regex :)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I use notepad++ for so long time that I forgot that notepad exists too :D